# Getting an error when trying to computer the smallest distance between two integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to calculate the shortest distance between any two numbers in an array that is sorted.  I am testing it with the algorithm below but I get the following error directly beneath; Which is stating that my array is out of bounds, so apparently it is trying to access an index that is not in the length of the array?  Not sure why as I have the check for the length in the for loop.  Does anyone have clue?

```
public static void getSmallestDistance(int[] integersCount)
{

    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < integersCount.length; i++  )
    {
        if( Math.abs(integersCount[index] - integersCount[index + 1]) >
        Math.abs( integersCount[i] - integersCount[i + 1]))//line 73 were error is
        {
            index = i;
        }



    }
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
at ClosestPair.getSmallestDistance(ClosestPair.java:73)
at ClosestPair.main(ClosestPair.java:57)
```

Comment: Consider what happens when `i` is `integersCount.length - 1`...

Comment: what is the error? please provide complete stack-trace as a good habit for getting better answers.

Comment: You are aware that the first entry has index 0 and the last 999?

Comment: @esej trace the usage of the `i` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the array's length is `integersCount.length` the max value of `i` is `integersCount.length - 1`, but you use `i+1` to index the array, which is out of bounds.

Therefore you need to run `i` from 0 or 1 (as needed) upto `integersCount.length - 2` that means  `i < integersCount.length - 2` or `i <= integersCount.length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i < integersCount.length; i++  )
```

should be

```
for(int i = 1; i < integersCount.length - 1; i++  )
```

This since you do:

```
integersCount[i + 1])
```

which (of course) throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` when i is at its max.

As some other answerers have pointed out, this is because java arrays are index from 0 to length-1 and at the last iteration of the for loop, i will be length-1 and i+1 will therefore be a too large index.

Answer (score 0):

`integersCount[i + 1]` in the loop causes the `"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"`

For example, if you have 10 items and in the last run of the for loop, i will be 9 and i + 1 will be 10 which will be out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

try changing for(int i = 1; i < integersCount.length; i++  ) to
for(int i = 0; i < integersCount.length; i++  )

I belive arrays start at adress 0 so you need to subtract 1 from the total number of contents to get to the last added number.

edit

changed integersCount.length-1 to the correct integersCount.length since it should be loweer than the number og addings, not lower then the numbers of addings - 1 ..

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i < integersCount.length; i++  )
{
  if( Math.abs(integersCount[index] - integersCount[index + 1]) >
      Math.abs( integersCount[i] - integersCount[i + 1]))//line 73 were error is 
      {
        index = i;
      }
```

when `i = integersCount.length - 1` which is the end of the array you are trying to use `integersCount[i + 1]` which obviously exceeds the array's bounds.